# JQuery Datepicker and PHP input parsing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to pass dates chosen by a user with the JQuery datepicker at my index.htlm form to the book.php form, and I believe there is a problem. So the code I use is:
**index.html:**

```
  <form id="check-book" name="check-book" method="post" action="/book.php">
  <fieldset>
   <label for="field_date_in">Дата заезда:</label> 
   <input type="text" id="field_date_in" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkin"/>
   <label for="field_date_out">Дата выезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_out" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkout"/>
   <input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Забронировать!">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

**book.php:**

```
<?php
 $field_date_in = $_REQUEST['sender_checkin'];
 $field_date_out = $_REQUEST['sender_checkout'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

 . . .

<form id="booking-form" name="contact-form" action="send-mail.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Контактная Информация</legend>
  <label for="field_name">Имя:</label>
  <input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name" placeholder="Введите Ваше Имя" autofocus/>
  <label for="field_email">E-mail:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="field_email"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" title="Пожалуйста введите e-mail" name="sender_email" placeholder="Введите Ваш e-mail">   
  <label for="field_phone">Номер телефона:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш Номер Телефона" >
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Информаци о бронировании</legend>
  <label for="room_selector">Выберите номер:</label><select name="room_selector" id="room_selector">
   <option value="eco_twin">Эконом (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="std_twin">Стандарт (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="std_double">Стандарт (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="attic_twin">Эконом Мансарда (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="attic_double">Эконом Мансарда (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="lux_twin">Люкс (Две кровати)</option>
   <option value="lux_double">Люкс (Двойная кровать)</option>
   <option value="lux_wed">Люкс Свадебный</option>
   <option value="lux_lux">Суперлюкс</option>
   </select>
   <label for="field_date_in">Дата заезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_in" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkin" value="<?php echo ($field_check_in);?>"/>
   <label for="field_date_out">Дата выезда:</label>
   <input type="text" id="field_date_out" size="8" readonly="readonly" name="sender_checkout" value="<?php echo $field_check_out;?>"/>
   <label for="field_guests">Количество гостей:</label>
   <input type="number" step="1" value="1" min="1" max="100" id="field_guests" name="sender_guests" />
   <label for="field_message">Сообщение:</label>
   <textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset> 
  <input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Отправить">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

However, once I choose the dates at index.html and press submit, book.php does not have the dates, the input areas are empty. I believe that might be due to the fact that Datepicker re-writes

```
 value class = "hasDatepicker"
```

so that value that is given by php does not apply any longer. How do I fix it?

Comment: where is code of `book.php`

Comment: What date format does the datepicker return?

Comment: Oops, sorry, there's a typo in my post, it's supposed to be **book.php**,  not **book.html**, will edit it now)